# Deploying On Remix Returned Error 32000 Gas Issue?

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, gas, evm

So i am trying to publish a smart contract using a guide.

https://github.com/tanishbaansal/legendary_token/blob/main/Legendary.sol

When i am trying to deploy to livenet it gives me the following error, it will deploy to remixes VM test net tho.

```
creation of Legendary errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"transaction underpriced\"}}}'","id":8631497957641221}
```

[image: Error]

[image: Metamask error]

Comment: What network are you deploying on? Are you deploying through Injected provider - MetaMask? I just deployed the contract on Goerli and it's 749,390 gas for the legendary contract deployment transaction.

Comment: I am deploying on BEP20 Using Metamask, I have tried larger gas fee on the remix interface but this does not change what metamask tries to charge me for gas.

Comment: I have just added an image of my screen,

Comment: When you compile the contract (assuming you have compiled legendary) and before you deploy, make sure you have there in the CONTRACT field on your screen selected Legendary.sol and not IBEP20.sol. Currently you are trying to deploy a different contract.

Comment: I had changed the name to it was deploying IBEP20.sol, But i have just tested again using legendary.sol i compiled it and tried to deploy with the same error. I have attached a new screenshot above including the metamask error received.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, you are deploying to the BNB Smart Chain mainnet (real funds). Just making sure it's your intent (to deploy on the mainnet with real funds and not the testnet). But to actually fix the error, in MetaMask, click on "Site suggested" and then play around with the settings (eg set to Aggressive) or just hit Advanced and make sure the Max base fee setting is above 4. This should work.

Comment: wow you are a life saver! I thought i was doing something wrong, just needed the aggressive selection on metamask. Top man thank you!